# adding appDir entry to requirejs optimizer build file results error

Tags: requirejs

When I add the appDir entry in the build file I get following error.

```
C:\Users\Thupten\Development\experiments>node r.js -o build.js
```

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at Function.build.makeAbsPath (C:\Users\Thupten\Development\experiments\r.js:22452:51)
```

Here is my build file

```
({
    appDir:"./SimpleRequireJsProject",
    baseUrl: "scripts",
    mainConfigFile: './SimpleRequireJsProject/scripts/main.js',
    include:'entrance.js',  //relative to baseUrl
    name:"main",
    out:"main-built.js",
    optimize:"none"
    })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem, running on msys.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the `appDir` option is incompatible with the `out` option, use the `dir` option instead. For example:

```
({
  appDir: '.',
  baseUrl: 'lib',
  dir: '../demo-build'
})
```